# matplotlib save every n steps for animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm simulating something with many time step, and there are a lot of steps involved. I would like to animate my results, plotting only one step every n.

Right now i have two non working propositions. The first one doesn't seem to loop correctly, and the second still fills the video with steps that are not update in the figure, making the file large and slow.

Can you help me ?

Thanks

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(256,256)
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
plot_every = 50
saved_steps = []
def make_step(s, t):
c = ...
    if (s%plot_every) == 0:
        print("plotting step {:.0f} , t ={:.0f} ".format(s, t*dt))
        ax.clear()
        ax.contourf(X, Y, c,
                np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.01),
                extend='both')
        saved_steps.append(ax)

for s , t in enumerate(range(t_steps)):
    make_step(s,t)

print("will now save anim")
def plot_ani(i):
    return saved_steps[i]

 anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plot_ani,range(len(saved_steps)) , interval=500,  blit=False)
```

or :

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
saved_steps = []
def make_step(s, t):  
    if (s%plot_every) == 0:
        print("plotting step {:.0f} , t ={:.0f} ".format(s, t*dt))
        ax.clear()
        ax.contourf(X, Y, c,
                np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.01),
                extend='both')
        return ax

 anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, make_step,range(len(saved_steps)) , interval=500,  blit=False)
```

and then i do

```
anim.save('spinodal_decompo_ex.ogv',  codec='libtheora')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on ImportanceofBeingErnest answer, here is what i came up with. The additional thing, is that `contourf` is not an `artist`, apparently...

```
fig = plt.figure()

saved_steps = []
def make_step(i, t):
    c = ...
    if (i%plot_every) == 0:
        print("plotting step {:.0f} , t ={:.0f} ".format(i, t*dt))
        im = plt.imshow(c, animated=True)
        saved_steps.append([im])

for s , t in enumerate(range(t_steps)):
    make_step(s, t)

print("will now save anim")
anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, saved_steps, interval=50, blit=False)

anim.save('spinodal_decompo_ex.ogv',  codec='libtheora', extra_args=['-qscale:v',  '7'])
```

thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Saving the matplotlib object creates a lot of unnecessary overhead. Sticking to the separation principle would eliminate this. But this is of course your own choice.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your first approach is that you try to store matplotlib `axes` objects in a list. However, the `ax` you store in the list is always the same. Once you call `ax.clear()` even the previously saved `ax` object will be cleared.

The problem with the second approach is that `FuncAnimation` will always save the figure for each time step. It does not matter, whether or not you change something in the axes.

Turning towards a solution:
A principle that is always wise to stick to is to **keep data generation and calculation separate from data visualization**.
The advise would therefore be to

First Calculate the data.

```
time_steps = 10000
data = []
for t in range(time_steps):
    d = calculate_data(t)
    data.append(d)
    # alternatively save data to file
    # if it's to big to be kept in memory.
```

Only then start visualization

```
# now start visualizing
plot_every = 50
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def make_step(step):  
    ax.clear()
    # recall data from list, but take only every 50th entry
    c = data[step*plot_every]  #alternatively reload data from file
    ax.contourf(X, Y, c, ...)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, make_step,range(time_steps//plot_every), interval=500)
```